# Discord - Send a private message without server

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello and before we start, this is mostly not a duplicated.

I want to create an application (**not a bot**).
That means, I don't need a Discord server or invite a bot in.
The only purpose of the application, it's to send private message to user with their ID.
In Discord, I can get freely ID of user in developer mode.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()
raidez_id = "SECRET"

token = None
with open("token.key") as fs:
    token = fs.readline()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
    user = await client.fetch_user(raidez_id)
    await user.send("Hello guys !")

client.run(token)
```

When I run this code, I got a 403 forbidden exception :
[image]
Mostly because a bot can send DM without permission of server !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bot user doesn’t have the necessary permissions to send you a direct message. If I’m correct, You need to have a mutual DM group or server, *or* be friends with the user. As this is a bot account, the only applicable answer is sharing a server. Unfortunately, I believe there is no way around this. Hope I could help!